# How to Freeze only subset of learnable parameter of one layer

Tags: pytorch

I want to freeze only a subset of parameter of linear layer.
is there any idea?

In the example below, I want to freeze only first 50 rows of parameters of Linear layer.

```
layer = nn.Linear(2048, 100)
# layer.weight.shape = (100, 2048)

# what i tried:
1. layer.weight[:50].requires_grad = False
=> RuntimeError: you can only change requires_grad flags of leaf variables. If you want to use a computed variable in a subgraph that doesn't require differentiation use var_no_grad = var.detach().

2. layer.weight.data[:50].requires_grad = False
=> print(layer.weight.requires_grad) : True

3. layer.weight[:50] = layer.weight[:50].detach()
=> RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be challenging to freeze a subset of parameters in a PyTorch module layer, specifically a portion of a weight matrix, because of how PyTorch manages gradients and views of tensors. This issue arises because you are attempting to treat a portion of a tensor differently from the rest in terms of gradient computation, which is not a straightforward process in PyTorch's computation graph.

However, you can do a workaround by creating a mask to disable the portion of parameters in backward process:

```
class PartiallyFrozenLinear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features, freeze_rows=50):
        super(PartiallyFrozenLinear, self).__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features

        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features))

        self.mask = torch.ones(out_features, in_features, requires_grad=False)
        self.mask[:freeze_rows] = 0

    def forward(self, input):
        return nn.functional.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

    def backward(self, grad_output):
        self.weight.grad *= self.mask
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I implemented it with autograd, and it works when the model is simple such as just simply stacked linear model. However, it doesn't work when the model is complicated even if the partiallyfrozenlayer is an auxiliary layer attached to backbone. I don't know why it doesnt work for my case, but I did it defining the parameters which i want to freeze as buffer.